# Tracing PCI device memory I/O operations in QEMU / VFIO environment

Tags: memory, trace, qemu, pci, vfio

I'm trying to reverse engineer some PCI device under QEMU / VFIO environment and I would like to trace all I/O operations on physical memory made by the card. The card makes use of PCI bus mastering and writes stuff to other devices and most probably reads some data preprocessed by driver from host RAM. As for now I was able to only trace all read and writes to the card MMIO space (data transfer from host to device), sadly I'm missing the second direction of R/W operations (device fetching data from host).

Is there a possibility to trace I/O operations that PCI device does on physical memory i.e. direct I/O and/or DMA transfers under QEMU / VFIO environment? I've enabled tracing for the following events:

> vfio_pci_read_config vfio_pci_write_config vfio_region_write
>   vfio_region_read vfio_intx_interrupt vfio_intx_eoi vfio_intx_update
>   vfio_intx_enable vfio_intx_disable vfio_msi_interrupt
>   vfio_populate_device_config vfio_region_mmap

Is there any event that allows to do such thing that can be registered in QEMU? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The PCI device is considered a peripheral device, which means it has its own processing unit and runs its own firmware. The access to mmio region occurs in the peripheral device and thus not traceable with QEMU.

It's possible to trace read/write to mmio in the QEMU VM because the memory instruction executed invokes a callback function to handle mmio access in VFIO.

Since the PCI device read/write mmio region in its firmware(executed by the device's processing unit), you are not able to trace the events on the host side.

I think what you can do is comparing mmio_read values with mmio_write values during reverse engineering.